# Number of Goldstone Modes in the Heisenberg Model?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking, spin-models, goldstone-mode

I am getting confused about the number of Goldstone modes present in the Heisenberg model. After a Holstein-Primakoff transformation the energy can be written a:
$$H=-JS^2 Nz+ \sum_{\vec k} \varepsilon(\vec k) a^\dagger(\vec k) a(\vec k)+\text{higher order terms}$$
where $a^\dagger(\vec k)$ and $a(\vec k)$ are Bosonic creation and annihilation operators and:
$$\varepsilon (\vec k)=2J S(3- \cos( k_x a) -\cos(k_y a)-\cos(k_z a))$$
To me this indicates $3$ independent Goldstone modes. But I have also read that we should have one Goldstone mode per continuous symmetry generator broken - from this I would expect $2$ Goldstone modes. This [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/317472/70392) on a related question also indicates that the Heisenberg model is an exception.

My question is therefore: How many Goldstone modes does the Heisenberg model have and why?

Comment: It is definitely not 3. Why would you say that ? Also, is the model with ferromagnetic or antiferromagnetic interactions ? That changes everything in that case.

Comment: @Adam Ferromagnetic. And $3$ modes as you appear to have a mode corresponding to $\vec k$ in the $x$, $y$ or $z$ direction.

Comment: You are making a huge confusion here : the dimension of space (related to the number of $k$ components) has nothing to do with the number of Goldstone modes (which is related to the number of internal symmetries not broken by the ground-state). For example, the O(N) model has N-1 Goldstone mode in any dimension d>2 (which is the lower-critical dimension).

Comment: @Adam Ok fair, If you expand on where this confusion lies - it may form a good answer.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Maybe helpful https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113773/number-of-goldstone-bosons-in-paramagnetic-to-ferromagnetic-phase-transitions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having a Goldstone mode at momentum $\boldsymbol k = (k_x,k_y,k_z)$ requires that the energy vanishes there, i.e. $\varepsilon(\boldsymbol k) = 0$. In the periodic Brillouin zone $\left[ -\frac{\pi}{a} , \frac{\pi}{a} \right] \times \left[ -\frac{\pi}{a} , \frac{\pi}{a} \right] \times \left[ -\frac{\pi}{a} , \frac{\pi}{a} \right]$, this only happens at the zone center, $\boldsymbol k = (0,0,0)$. More precisely, for small momenta, we have that $$\varepsilon(\boldsymbol k) \approx JSa^2 (k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2).$$

So we seemingly have only *one* Goldstone mode. How does this rhyme with the number of Goldstone modes being equal to the number of broken symmetry-generators (which is indeed *two* in this case)?

The answer that the above rule of thumb for counting Goldstone modes is true for relativistic theories, where the Goldstone modes have a low-energy dispersion $\varepsilon \sim |\boldsymbol k|$. However, in the above case, our low-energy dispersion is *quadratic*. Indeed, the more general formula is given in this 1976 article "[*On how to count Goldstone bosons*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321376900250?via%3Dihub)" by Nielsen and Chadha: the modes where $\varepsilon_{\boldsymbol k} \sim |\boldsymbol k|^z$ count *double* if $z$ is even. Hence, $$ \# \left(\textrm{broken generators}\right) = \# \left(\textrm{Goldstone modes with $z$ odd} \right) + 2 \# \left( \textrm{Goldstone modes with $z$ even} \right). $$

Example: the *ferromagnetic* Heisenberg model has *one* Goldstone mode with a *quadratic* dispersion, whereas the *antiferromagnetic* Heisenberg model has *two* Goldstone modes with a *linear* dispersion. In both cases, this agrees with the number of broken generators being *two*.

Comment: Related reference: _Unified Description of Nambu-Goldstone Bosons without Lorentz Invariance_ https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.0609 @RubenVerresen